# SKAction sequence runBlock, actions within?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a sequence of `SKActions` setup and they work.  However, if I spawn actions within a `SKAction runBlock:^{}`, those actions run too, but the parent sequence doesn't wait for them to finish.  How can I accomplish behavior where, when running a sequence, the parent sequence waits for the **actions** **within** **a** `runBlock` to complete also?

Comment: Blocks are meant for asynchronous execution. This will not be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is simply not possible. `runBlock` fires once and then goes on with the following action. However, you could check in e.g. `didFinishUpdate` whether some condition is met and then run other actions. But you should not overuse this and rather look whether you can accomplish the desired actions with plain `SKActions`.